# Can not send ampersand + curren via curl post ($currency=A&otherkey=B)

Tags: php, curl, post, currency, ampersand

I got problem with **ampersand + curren** in my POST string on curl processing - instead POST values I got sunny character - ¤.

My question is:
how to send

['**currency**' => 'somevalue', 'otherkey' => 'othervalue']

with **POST** via **curl**.

I tried to form my POST as

`$post_val = "otherVal=1&currency=USD";`

or

`$post_val = "otherVal=1&amp;currency=USD";`

or

`$post_val = urlencode("otherVal=1&amp;currency=USD");`

and then

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_val);`

What is strange - it gives the same effect when I pass currency as first in string - "currency=USD&otherVal=1".

Also I tried

`$array = http_build_query(['currency' => 'somevalue', 'otherkey' => 'othervalue']);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);`

Perhaps curl allways make http_build_query which also gives some additional signs which the source server can not interpret correctly?

Any ideas how to solve it?

cheers

Comment: `&curren;` translates to the currency symbol ¤. But when `&currency` or even `&amp;currency` translate to the same symbol, this is a bit strange indeed. Do you see this symbol on the server side, in your `$_POST` array?

Comment: Have you tried `$post_val = array('otherVal' => 1, 'currency' => 'USD');` ?

Comment: Unfortunetely I have no insight into server side. I just conclude about the effect. Sending one post value -> correct, sending few -> error.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way out

```
$data = array('otheritem'=>'item', 'currency'=>'usd');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

this should work